# Extracting coefficients, standard errors and p-values of selected variables from doing regression many times

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have the following hypothetical data.

```
library(data.table)

city <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)                                       
village <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)                              
village_status <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
y <- c(1,1,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
x1 <- c(2,5,4,4,3,4,5,3,2,1,3,5,1,5,4,5)
x2  <- c(21,33,46,8,19,30,20,2,34,38,19,89,35,67,60,37)
x3 <-  c(23,28,30,15,7,18,29,27,14,22,24,10,12,6,17,10)
datei <- data.table(city, village, village_status, y, x1, x2, x3)
```

What I want to do is the following:

1. I want to randomize village status 1000 times by shuffling village according to city
2. I want to do regression 1000 times using the randomized village status in each of the regression.
3. I want to extract the coefficient, standard errors and p value of the randomized village status and store them as data.table

For the first and second point, I already did the following:

1. I shuffled village status and put the randomized village status in new columns (randomvil1, randomvil2, ..., randomvil1000)

```
n <- 1000
datei[, paste0("randomvil", 1:n) := replicate(n, sample(village_status), simplify=F), city]
```

2. I did the regression 1000 times using lapply

```
library(estimatr)

# Extract the randomized village columns
varvil0 <- c(paste0("randomvil", 1:n)) 
varvil <- datei[,..varvil0]


fit <- lapply(varvil, function(randomvil) lm_robust(y~ randomvil + randomvil:x1 + x2 + x3 + factor(city), data=datei, se_type= "stata", clusters= city))
```

Now, I want to extract the the coefficients, standard errors and p-values of randomvil and randomvil:x1 and store them as data.table. What I expect is something similar to this.

```
|               | Estimate     | Std. Error |    Pr(>|t|)  |
| ------------- | ------------ | --------   | --------     |
| randomvil1    | -0.945474623 | 0.474268   |   0.1843847  |
| randomvil1:x1 | -0.004905517 | 0.012388   |   0.7303777  |
| randomvil2    | -0.005449813 | 0.022198   |   0.828959   |
| randomvil2:x1 | -0.341242368 | 0.167598   |   0.1786814  |
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: `summary(fit)$coef` gives you the coefficient table as a matrix. That's easy to change to a data.table and `rbindlist` would combine everything. The permutation could (should) just be an addition column.

Comment: I avoid solutions that require adding 1000 columns to a data table.  I’ll bet there is a way to do the 1000 model fits without storing the randomized values.

Comment: @FrankHarrell  I agree with you. My codes are inefficient. But, I dont know how to do it in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the relevant coefficients you can do

```
result <- do.call(what = "rbind",
                  args = lapply(
                    X = fit, 
                    FUN = \(x) coef(summary(x)) |>  
                      { \(x) x[c("randomvil", "randomvil:x1"), 
                               c("Estimate", "Std. Error",  "Pr(>|t|)")] }()
                    )) |>
  # currently a matrix 
  `rownames<-`(c(rbind(paste0("randomvil", 1L:1e3), 
                       paste0("randomvil", 1L:1e3, ":x1")))) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  data.table::setDT(keep.rownames = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
> head(result)
              rn      Estimate Std. Error   Pr(>|t|)
1:    randomvil1 -0.1535707146 0.47420395 0.77678174
2: randomvil1:x1  0.0002317025 0.16725807 0.99902045
3:    randomvil2  0.8757044386 0.25611745 0.07592514
4: randomvil2:x1 -0.1845974571 0.07522312 0.13357686
5:    randomvil3  0.0857456330 0.32624900 0.81728482
6: randomvil3:x1 -0.0672697523 0.10371047 0.58310677
```

You might prefer `keep.rownames = "id"`.

Notice that,

```
c(rbind(paste0("randomvil", 1L:1e3), 
        paste0("randomvil", 1L:1e3, ":x1")))
```

is a hacky, easy, and possibly error-prone way to rename the coefficients.

Comment: It worked. Thank you! Anyway, why is it  possibly error-prone way?